# How to convert an array of strings to an array of floats in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, type-conversion

How do I make the following conversion in NumPy?

```
["1.1", "2.2", "3.2"]  ⟶  [1.1, 2.2, 3.2]
```

Answer (score 263, accepted):

Well, if you're reading the data in as a list, just do `np.array(map(float, list_of_strings))` (or equivalently, use a list comprehension). (In Python 3, you'll need to call `list` on the `map` return value if you use `map`, since `map` returns an iterator now.)

However, if it's already a numpy array of strings, there's a better way.  Use `astype()`.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array(['1.1', '2.2', '3.3'])
y = x.astype(np.float)
```

Comment: and if you have a array with an string that i want to maintain? like ['a','1.1','2.2','3.3'] -> ['a',1.1,2.2,3.3]

Comment: @MrMartin - Then use a `list`.  Numpy arrays are deliberately homogenously typed.  If you really want, you can use an object array (e.g. `np.array(['apple', 1.2, 1, {'b'=None, 'c'=object()}], dtype=object)`).  However, object arrays don't have any significant advantages over using a list.

Comment: ```print(list(y))``` gives ```[1.1, 2.2, 3.3]

[Program finished] ``` as requested by OP

Comment: Does not work if any of the strings is an empty string ('').

Answer (score 20):

Another option might be [numpy.asarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html):

```
import numpy as np
a = ["1.1", "2.2", "3.2"]
b = np.asarray(a, dtype=float)

print(a, type(a), type(a[0]))
print(b, type(b), type(b[0]))
```

resulting in:

```
['1.1', '2.2', '3.2'] <class 'list'> <class 'str'>
[1.1 2.2 3.2] <class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.float64'>
```

Comment: I benchmarked all the answers here in python 2.7. Assuming I'm given a list of 512 strings which represent floating point numbers, this approach was the fastest (slightly faster than pradeep bisht's answer, about 1.5 times faster than Thomio's answer, and more than twice as fast as the accepted answer). Have an upvote!

Comment: "order='C'" is not needed here since this is a 1-dim array. This also works (at least in Python 3.6.9):
  b=np.array(a, dtype=float)

Comment: add `.tolist()` at the end, like that `b = np.asarray(d, dtype=np.float64).tolist()` to get comma separated list

Answer (score 7):

If you have (or create) a single string, you can use **np.fromstring**:

```
import numpy as np
x = ["1.1", "2.2", "3.2"]
x = ','.join(x)
x = np.fromstring( x, dtype=np.float, sep=',' )
```

Note, `x = ','.join(x)` transforms the x array to string `'1.1, 2.2, 3.2'`. If you read a line from a txt file, each line will be already a string.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `np.array()` with `dtype = float`:

```
import numpy as np

x = ["1.1", "2.2", "3.2"]
y = np.array(x,dtype=float)
```

Output:

```
array([1.1, 2.2, 3.2])
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use this as well

```
import numpy as np
x=np.array(['1.1', '2.2', '3.3'])
x=np.asfarray(x,float)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array that contains invalid values such as an empty string (`''`), then a straightforward casting would raise an error. If you just want to convert this "problematic" array into a numpy float array and handle the invalid values later, then `pandas` package has a function (`pandas.to_numeric`) that sets invalid values to NaN and converts the rest to float.

```py
import pandas as pd

a = np.array(["1.1", "2.2"], float)      # OK

lst = ["1.1", "2.2", "3.2.", ""]
a = np.array(lst, float)                 # ValueError: could not convert string to float: '3.2.'
a = pd.to_numeric(lst, errors='coerce')  # array([1.1, 2.2, nan, nan])
```