# How to set precision of numpy float array when converting from string array?

Tags: python, numpy

I am using the following link to convert a array of string to array of float
[Convert String to float array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877209/how-to-convert-an-array-of-strings-to-an-array-of-floats-in-numpy)

The data that I am getting is in a weird format

```
535.    535.    535.    534.68  534.68  534.68
```

Although numpy is able to convert the string array to float but some other is failing when data is in the format **535.**

Is there a way to convert all **535.** to **535.00** in one go.

I am using the following code for conversions

```
import numpy as np
strarray = ["535.","535.","534.68"]
floatarray = np.array(filter(None,strarray),dtype='|S10').astype(np.float)
print floatarray
```

Comment: the data do you get in by any chance from a txt file before you put it in a string array ?
(535. and 535.00 are the same in calculations so your problem is in printing isn't it ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the the strings to `float128`.
Try this:

```
import numpy as np
strarray = ["535.","535.","534.68"]
floatarray = np.array(filter(None,strarray),dtype='|S10').astype(np.float128)
print floatarray
```

Output:

```
[ 535.0  535.0  534.68]
```

Or use the recommended `longdouble`:

```
import numpy as np
strarray = ["535.","535.","534.68"]
floatarray = np.array(filter(None,strarray),dtype='|S10').astype(np.longdouble)
print floatarray
```

Output:

```
[ 535.0  535.0  534.68]
```

Comment: float128 is not working on pydev python 2.7, not sure what is the problem but np.longdouble is working fine