# Using scipy.optimize.curve_fit

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am new to scipy and I am unable to use the `curve_fit` function. I think there is some scipy/numpy  data wrapper that needs to be used for independent and dependent data sets.  The windowCurrent and windowVoltage are queues that hold a sliding set of points from my data set.

How can I wrap the list of current/voltage pairs to avoid this error?

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Code:

```
for line in inputFileContents[:maxlen]:
    print line
    timeStamp,voltage,current = line.split(",")
    if windowCurrent == None and windowVoltage == None:
        windowCurrent = deque(current, maxlen)
        windowVoltage = deque(voltage, maxlen)
    else:
        windowCurrent.append(current)
        windowVoltage.append(voltage)

for lineConents in inputFileContents:
    timeStamp,voltage,current = line.split(",")
    windowCurrent.append(current)
    windowVoltage.append(voltage)
    curveList.append([timeStamp, op.curve_fit(logCurve, np.array(list(windowCurrent)), np.array(list(windowVoltage)))])
    curveListPopulate(curveList)
```

Also: doing `list(windowCurrent)`, leaving off the `np.array` wrapping, also returns an error.

[Link](http://pastebin.com/XM5V9msF) to full text of error

Comment: Which error do you get when leaving off `np.array()`?

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try converting `current` and `voltage` to `float` before appending them to `windowCurrent` and `windowVoltage`.

**Explanation:**

Numpy's arrays can hold a variety of data types, not only numbers. In your case, it seems to be a string datatype: `line.split` returns strings, and thus you get a numpy array of strings. Obviously, you can't subtract strings from each other.

Comment: That was a bit of a derp on my part.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with silvado, the problem is in passing string numpy arrays to curve_fit.

This might help in resolving problem:

[How to convert an array of strings to an array of floats in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877209/how-to-convert-an-array-of-strings-to-an-array-of-floats-in-numpy)

Comment: I just edited the way I was adding each item to the deque windows.  Thanks though