# How to convert an array of strings to a record array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This is similar to [How to convert an array of strings to an array of floats in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3877209/327026).

I have a list of strings:

```
dat = [
    '  1  2  1.040000e+005  0.030000\n',
    '  2  7  0.000000e+000  0.030000\n',
    '  3  15  0.000000e+000  0.030000\n',
]
```

Here are my failed attempts to make a numpy record array:

```
import numpy as np
dat_dtype = [
    ('I', 'i'),
    ('J', 'i'),
    ('val1', 'd'),
    ('val2', 'd'),
]

# Attempt 1
np.array(dat, dat_dtype)
# looks like garbage

# Attempt 2
np.array([x.split() for x in dat], dtype=dat_dtype)
# looks like different garbage

# Attempt 3
string_ndarray = np.array([x.split() for x in dat], dtype='|S15')
# looks good so far
string_ndarray.astype(dat_dtype)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.040000e+005'
```

I give up. Here's the only way I can get the expected output:

```
dat_ndarray = np.zeros(len(dat), dat_dtype)
for i, line in enumarate(dat):
    dat_ndarray[i] = tuple(line.split())

print(dat_ndarray)  # [(1, 2, 104000.0, 0.03) (2, 7, 0.0, 0.03) (3, 15, 0.0, 0.03)]
```

Is there a more direct method to get the expected record array?

Comment: Well you should also indicate what you are expecting output as.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is lines of text, so you can use a text reader to convert it to an array (structured or plain).  Here's one way to do that with [`numpy.genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html):

```
np.genfromtxt(dat, dtype=dat_dtype)
```

For example,

```
In [204]: dat
Out[204]: 
['  1  2  1.040000e+005  0.030000\n',
 '  2  7  0.000000e+000  0.030000\n',
 '  3  15  0.000000e+000  0.030000\n']

In [205]: dat_dtype
Out[205]: [('I', 'i'), ('J', 'i'), ('val1', 'f'), ('val2', 'f')]

In [206]: np.genfromtxt(dat, dtype=dat_dtype)
Out[206]: 
array([(1, 2, 104000.0, 0.029999999329447746), (2, 7, 0.0, 0.029999999329447746), (3, 15, 0.0, 0.029999999329447746)], 
      dtype=[('I', '<i4'), ('J', '<i4'), ('val1', '<f4'), ('val2', '<f4')])
```

Comment: This looks undocumented, as the first argument `fname` is neither a file or string.

Comment: The documentation [is now corrected](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/ae2d0bb7c2d227e893195cc3e52477567781e2db) to describe this feature;

Answer (score 1):

With your `dat` and `dat_dtype` this works:

```
In [667]: np.array([tuple(x.strip().split()) for x in dat],dtype=dat_dtype)
Out[667]: 
array([(1, 2, 104000.0, 0.03), (2, 7, 0.0, 0.03), (3, 15, 0.0, 0.03)], 
  dtype=[('I', '<i4'), ('J', '<i4'), ('val1', '<f8'), ('val2', '<f8')])
```

Structured arrays are best created with lists of tuples.  I stripped off the `\n`, split it on white space,  and then formed tuples

```
In [668]: [tuple(x.strip().split()) for x in dat]
Out[668]: 
[('1', '2', '1.040000e+005', '0.030000'),
 ('2', '7', '0.000000e+000', '0.030000'),
 ('3', '15', '0.000000e+000', '0.030000')]
```

I let the `dat_dtype` take care of the string to number conversion.

Comment: This is the same as my attempt 2, but with `tuple(x.split())`. It doesn't seem that white space matters.

Comment: Yes, the `.strip()` wasn't needed.  It's just a habit from reading text lines - remove the `\n` before splitting into words.  Without the `tuple` the best you get is an array of strings.