# Python: the fastest way to translate numpy string array to a number array

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, numbers

anyone can tell me what is the fastest way to translate this  string array into a number array as below:

```
import numpy as np
strarray = np.array([["123456"], ["654321"]])

     to

numberarray = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6], [6,5,4,3,2,1]])
```

map str to list and then map str to int is too slow for a large array!

Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert an array of strings to an array of floats in numpy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877209/how-to-convert-an-array-of-strings-to-an-array-of-floats-in-numpy)

Comment: Is this typo? ["12456"] -> [1,2,**3**,4,5,6]

Comment: Are all elements guaranteed to have the same length (like it's 6 in the sample case)?

Comment: To lan: Yes, that is  a typo！already correct that!

Comment: To Divakar: Yes, guaranteed to have the same length!!

Comment: To idjaw: that is different from my question. I want to separate a string (no delimiter) array into a number array, the original string is quite long(320 digits), I am seeking an efficient way to do this kind of translation

Answer (score 3):

You can split the strings into single characters with the array `view` method:

```
In [18]: strarray = np.array([[b"123456"], [b"654321"]])

In [19]: strarray.dtype
Out[19]: dtype('S6')

In [20]: strarray.view('S1')
Out[20]: 
array([['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'],
       ['6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1']], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

See [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#specifying-and-constructing-data-types) for data type character codes.

Then the most obvious next step is to use `astype`:

```
In [23]: strarray.view('S1').astype(int)
Out[23]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]])
```

However, it's a lot faster to reinterpret (view) the memory underlying the strings as single byte integers and subtract 48. This works because ASCII characters take up a single byte and the characters `'0'` through `'9'` are binary equivalent to (u)int8's 48 through 57 (check the [`ord` builtin](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord)).

Speed comparison:

```
In [26]: ar = np.array([[''.join(np.random.choice(list('123456789'), size=320))] for _ in range(1000)], bytes)

In [27]: %timeit _ = ar.view('S1').astype(np.uint8)
1 loops, best of 3: 284 ms per loop

In [28]: %timeit _ = ar.view(np.uint8) - ord('0')
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.07 ms per loop
```

If have Unicode instead of ASCII you need to do these steps slightly different. Or just convert to ASCII first with `astype(bytes)`.

Comment: Could be a version issue, I am getting unicode for `strarray.dtype`. I am on Python 3.4. And `ar.view('S1')` has `"b'"` all over alongwith the strings themselves.

Comment: @Divakar - I changed the strings to bytes for Python 3 compatibility.

Comment: But if OP has those as strings, he/she has to convert to byte first, right? How could that be done?

Comment: @Divakar - Python 2.x has ASCII strings as default and for those it works.

Comment: Ah yes you have mentioned `.astype(bytes)` for the conversion in the post! Nice, works for me now.

Comment: @morningsun Great solution! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that converts the input strings to N-length numeric arrays, i.e. each string gets converted to a 1D array of length `N`, where `N` is the length of each of those strings.
The approach suggested here basically converts the string to their `int` equivalents and then gets all the digits using  differentiation from their preceding elements' `power-10` scaled version. The implementation looks like this -

```
A = (strarray.astype(int)/(10**np.arange(len(strarray[0][0])))).astype(int)
out = np.column_stack((A[:,-1],(A[:,:-1] - 10*A[:,1:])[:,::-1]))
```

Sample run -

```
In [177]: strarray  = np.array([["0308468"], ["6540542"], ["4973473"]])

In [178]: A = (strarray.astype(int)/(10**np.arange(len(strarray[0][0])))).astype(int)
     ...: out = np.column_stack((A[:,-1],(A[:,:-1] - 10*A[:,1:])[:,::-1]))
     ...: 

In [179]: out
Out[179]: 
array([[0, 3, 0, 8, 4, 6, 8],
       [6, 5, 4, 0, 5, 4, 2],
       [4, 9, 7, 3, 4, 7, 3]])
```

Comment: Tricky solution! Thanks for providing this method for lighting me up!