# pandas - different dtype column before/after reading a file

Tags: python, pandas

I'm referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35746039/pandas-get-nested-string-values-from-arrays) question since I'm facing with a weird behaviour of column types before and after reading the same dataframe from a .csv. Starting from:

```
In [137]: df
Out[137]: 
    node1  node2 lang  w c1 c2
0       1      2   it  1  a  a
1       1      2   en  1  a  a
2       2      3   es  2  a  b
3       3      4   it  1  b  b
4       5      6   it  1  c  c
5       3      5   tg  1  b  c
6       1      7   it  1  a  a
7       7      1   es  1  a  a
8       3      8   es  1  b  b
9       8      4   es  1  b  b
10      1      9   it  1  a  a
```

Then performing a groupby:

```
In [138]: g = df.groupby(['c1','c2'])['lang'].unique().reset_index()

In [139]: g
Out[139]: 
  c1 c2          lang
0  a  a  [it, en, es]
1  a  b          [es]
2  b  b      [it, es]
3  b  c          [tg]
4  c  c          [it]
```

and get the values of the `lang` column returns:

```
In [148]: g['lang'].values
Out[148]: 
array([array(['it', 'en', 'es'], dtype=object),
       array(['es'], dtype=object), array(['it', 'es'], dtype=object),
       array(['tg'], dtype=object), array(['it'], dtype=object)], dtype=object)
```

Then if I:

```
In [141]: g.to_csv('g.csv',index=False)

In [142]: g = pd.read_csv('g.csv')

In [143]: g
Out[143]: 
  c1 c2              lang
0  a  a  ['it' 'en' 'es']
1  a  b            ['es']
2  b  b       ['it' 'es']
3  b  c            ['tg']
4  c  c            ['it']

In [145]: g['lang'].values
Out[145]: array(["['it' 'en' 'es']", "['es']", "['it' 'es']", "['tg']", "['it']"], dtype=object)
```

So reading the file from .csv leads to an array of string which is more complex to handle than the original array of arrays before writing/reading the dataframe. Anyone knows whether there is a way to keep the same format after reading the dataframe from file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use [pickle IO](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_pickle.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [['a', 'b']]})
df.a.dtype
df.to_pickle('stuff.pkl.bin')
>>> pd.read_pickle('stuff.pkl.bin').a
0    [a, b]
Name: a, dtype: object
```

CSV is a very limited, textual, format. Conversely, [`pickle` (and its variants)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) are binary object formats.