# How to serialize a column of vectors to a file and be able to read it back

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame a column of which I want it to store numeric vectors. I can easily do that. But If I want to serialize that to a file and then retrieve it back it becomes quite messy

Here is a snippet similar to my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['vector', 'other_col'])
for _ in range(1,10):
    df.loc[len(df), 'vector'] = np.random.rand(2000)
df.to_csv('example.csv', index=False)

data = pd.read_csv('example.csv')
```

the data will look like this

```
                                              vector  other_col
0  [ 0.44182594  0.38653563  0.55276495 ...,  0.6...        NaN
1  [ 0.15619965  0.97775275  0.6904491  ...,  0.2...        NaN
2  [ 0.80848747  0.66653121  0.37620277 ...,  0.5...        NaN
3  [ 0.41350165  0.40033263  0.39881338 ...,  0.3...        NaN
4  [ 0.17602205  0.54945447  0.49621991 ...,  0.6...        NaN
5  [ 0.75765499  0.09553434  0.14637461 ...,  0.2...        NaN
```

as you can see instead of the vectors what gets stored to the file is the actual string that you would see in your stdout if you tried to print the content of the dataframe

I have some workarounds in mind, I am just curious whether it's feasible to have that particular solution

Comment: Please show code where you believe that you get dots instead of values, this is probably a display thing and will not happen when writing to a real file. For instance if you did `to_string()` you will see all values

Comment: I think you need [pickle IO](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_pickle.html) - [see](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35748044/2901002)

Comment: Add code and data that reproduces this error that others can reproduce

Comment: @EdChum, please let me know if you think that it's still unclear what the problem is

Comment: OK, this maybe some kind of limitation or bug, it seems to be converting the array to a string for some reason which I don't understand. I'd expect `np.savetxt` to work but generally storing non-scalar values as data elements is not a good idea even if this did work

Comment: How about using `df.to_pickle(filename)`? -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/17098736/478237

Comment: I too think that it's a bad idea what I am trying to, It is just tempting to give it a chance when you have labeled data and want to use them later for feature extraction for which you don't know the features yet. `df.to_pickle` does not a look a good candidate when you want to have some In-dependency between the data and the tools that you use to manipulate them