# Convert string type array to array

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have  this:

```
[s[8] = 5,

 s[4] = 3,

 s[19] = 2,

 s[17] = 8,

 s[16] = 8,

 s[2] = 8,

 s[9] = 7,

 s[1] = 2,

 s[3] = 9,

 s[15] = 7,

 s[11] = 0,

 s[10] = 9,

 s[12] = 3,

 s[18] = 1,

 s[0] = 4,

 s[14] = 5,

 s[7] = 4,

 s[6] = 2,

 s[5] = 7,

 s[13] = 9]
```

How can I turn this into a python array where I can do `for items in x:` ?

Comment: What kind of data-structure is that? It has the list brackets around it but contains notation to set key and value in a dict?

Comment: Are you sure it is the original chunk of code?

Comment: Is that a string in your code?

Comment: I have this array, not sorted, each item have value, yes

Comment: here is solved example with [numpy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877209/how-to-convert-an-array-of-strings-to-an-array-of-floats-in-numpy)

Comment: Yes, I have it as string

Comment: Then edit you answer to mentioned it as string. `"` around each item

Comment: What is the expected output? please also mention that

Comment: Its definitely a string, couldn't edit it, it kept showing me error that its not formatted. So I can't add quotes. Expected output is as I said an array, S array where I can `print s[0]` and get it's value. S string should turn into actual python array

Comment: Just to be clear, are you looking for an [array](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/array.html), or a [list](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#list)?

Comment: You want us to turn that string into a dictionary with the left side of the equation as the key and the right side as the value?

Comment: Array, `print s[9]` should print 7

Comment: I am assuming, you have the above list, let's say `my_list` and another list as `s`. On doing `my_list[0]`, it should execute `s[8] = 5` and set `8`th index of `s` as `8`. Is it the case?

Comment: No, I receive this data as is through socket

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but I'd suggest changing the communication format if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import re

data = """[s[8] = 5,

 s[4] = 3,

 s[19] = 2,

 s[17] = 8,

 s[16] = 8,

 s[2] = 8,

 s[9] = 7,

 s[1] = 2,

 s[3] = 9,

 s[15] = 7,

 s[11] = 0,

 s[10] = 9,

 s[12] = 3,

 s[18] = 1,

 s[0] = 4,

 s[14] = 5,

 s[7] = 4,

 s[6] = 2,

 s[5] = 7,

 s[13] = 9]"""

d = {int(m.group(1)): int(m.group(2)) for m in re.finditer(r"s\[(\d*)\] = (\d*)", data)}
seq = [d.get(x) for x in range(max(d))]
print(seq)
#result: [4, 2, 8, 9, 3, 7, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 0, 3, 9, 5, 7, 8, 8, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the array to have the same name that is in the input string, you could use exec. This is not very pythonic, but it works for simple stuff

```
string = ("[s[8] = 5, s[4] = 3, s[19] = 2,"
   "s[17] = 8, s[16] = 8, s[2] = 8,"
   "s[9] = 7,  s[1] = 2,  s[3] = 9,"
   "s[15] = 7, s[11] = 0, s[10] = 9,"
   "s[12] = 3, s[18] = 1, s[0] = 4,"
   "s[14] = 5, s[7] = 4,  s[6] = 2,"
   "s[5] = 7, s[13] = 9]")

items = [item.rstrip().lstrip() for item in string[1:-1].split(",")]
name = items[0].partition("[")[0]
# Create the array
exec("{} = [None] * {}".format(name, len(items)))
# Populate with the values of the string
for item in items:
    exec(items[0].partition("[")[0] )
```

This will generate an array named "s" and if there is an index missing it will be initialized as None

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is one giant string, if you want `print s[0]` to print `4`, then you need to split this up by the commas, then iterate through each item.

```
inputArray = yourInput[1:-1].replace(' ','').split(',\n\n')
endArray = [0]*20
for item in inputArray:
    endArray[int(item[item.index('[')+1:item.index(']')])]= int(item[item.index('=')+1:])
print endArray
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way, although less efficient than Kevin's solution (without using regular expressions), would be the following (where `some_array` is your string):

```
sub_list = some_array.split(',')
some_dict = {}

for item in sub_list:
    sanitized_item = item.strip().rstrip().lstrip().replace('=', ':')

    # split item in key val
    k = sanitized_item.split(':')[0].strip()
    v = sanitized_item.split(':')[1].strip()

    if k.startswith('['):
        k = k.replace('[', '')

    if v.endswith(']'):
        v = v.replace(']', '')

    some_dict.update({k: int(v)})

print(some_dict)
print(some_dict['s[9]'])
```

Output sample:

```
{'s[5]': 7, 's[16]': 8, 's[0]': 4, 's[9]': 7, 's[2]': 8, 's[3]': 9, 's[10]': 9, 's[15]': 7, 's[6]': 2, 's[7]': 4, 's[14]': 5, 's[19]': 2, 's[17]': 8, 's[4]': 3, 's[12]': 3, 's[11]': 0, 's[13]': 9, 's[18]': 1, 's[1]': 2, 's8]': 5}
7
```