# Evaluating complex expressions with ast.literal_eval()

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-3.x, numpy

I am running python 3.5 and trying to convert a large string of strings into a numpy array.

I used the [answer from stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877209/how-to-convert-an-array-of-strings-to-an-array-of-floats-in-numpy) to put this code together.

```
import ast
import numpy as np
str = '["8.4","4.3E-7"]'
arr = ast.literal_eval(str)
x = np.array(arr, dtype='|S4')
y = x.astype(np.float32)
```

I am getting the folllowing value error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '4.3E'
```

str is an example string , most of the numbers don't have E-something pattern, but occasionally this happens and my code hangs up.

is there a way to convert string to numpy array in this case?

Comment: `|S4` is a max length of 4 characters. You didn't give enough room.

Comment: You don't need to specify the dtype at all, though. It'll be inferred for you. (I'll go edit that other answer to clarify things.)

Comment: @user2357112 if u just post an answer, Ill be able to place accept officially. thanks for the answer though... turns out there is a lot to learn from this community  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input contains a 6 character long string representation of a number (`4.3E-7`) but you tell `numpy` to import only upto 4 characters. Change the `dtype='|S4'` to `dtype='|S6'`, or indeed remove it entirely and let numpy figure out the length of the strings. Also, make sure to avoid overwriting `str` to avoid headaches down the line!

```
import ast
import numpy as np
s = '["8.4","4.3E-7"]' # don't overwrite str!
arr = ast.literal_eval(s)
x = np.array(arr) # changed length
y = x.astype(np.float32)
```

Comment: It's simpler to just remove the dtype specifier entirely and let NumPy figure out how much room the strings need.