# How to convert only integars of an array of strings to an array of floats in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

How to convert

```
["5", "3","Code", "9","Pin"]
```

to

```
[5, 3,"Code", 9,"Pin"]
```

in NumPy?

It is similar to this question [How to convert an array of strings to an array of floats in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877209/how-to-convert-an-array-of-strings-to-an-array-of-floats-in-numpy) with the exception of having words as well is there a way?

Comment: It would seem your question is answered in the comments of the top answer of the question you've linked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to check if the elements in the list are numeric or not, and return a string or an `int` accordingly:

```
l = ["5", "3","Code", "9","Pin"]

[int(i) if i.isnumeric() else i for i in l]
```

**Output**

```
[5, 3, 'Code', 9, 'Pin']
```

Comment: `float(i)` if OP *really* is looking for an *array of floats*, however the expected output in the question suggests otherwise.

Comment: No, you cannot convert into floats directly because `isnumeric()` will not work as excepted for floats wrapped in string. For example `'5.4'.isnumeric()` will return `False` but will work for `int`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your list can contain both int and float. (Your reference contains float, and your example contains list), you can use a list comprehension like below :

```
l = ["5", "3","Code", "9", "4.5", "Pin"]

def isfloat(value):
    try:
        float(value)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

l = [int(elem) if elem.isnumeric() else (float(elem) if isfloat(elem) else elem) for elem in l]
```

It would return the following array :

```
[5, 3, "Code", 9, 4.5, "Pin"]
```