# ValueError: could not convert string to float solution

Tags: python, graph, floating-point

I have a text file containing data. The data, in this case, are simply the numbers '0.049371 0.049371 0.000000'.

I have the code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.loadtxt("/path/to/file", delimiter=",")

plt.figure()

plt.plot(range(len(data)), data, color='blue')
plt.xlim(0, 100)
plt.ylim(0, 50)
plt.xlabel('t / t₀', fontstyle = 'italic')
plt.ylabel('Speed', fontstyle = 'italic')



plt.show()
```

But I get the error message 'ValueError: could not convert string to float'. Is there a way to convert all of the values in a text file to floats?

Thank you

Comment: Are your values actually separated by commas?

Comment: May I suggest you copy and paste several lines of the text file into a code block so that we know what kind of data we are working with?

Comment: They weren't separated by commas. I have changed the delimiter and it is solved now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line `data = np.loadtxt("/path/to/file", delimiter=",")` you have specified `","` as the delimiter. This would give the correct result if your file contained `0.049371,0.049371,0.000000`.

Since the numbers are actually separated by spaces, use:

```
data = np.loadtxt("/path/to/file", delimiter=" ")
```

or just:

```
data = np.loadtxt("/path/to/file")
```

Answer (score 1):

numpy.loadtext returns an array so you could use `fdata = data.astype(np.float)`

[How to convert an array of strings to an array of floats in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877209/how-to-convert-an-array-of-strings-to-an-array-of-floats-in-numpy)